# Typhoon auto-inject assembly by protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

I'm having a problem with correctly acquiring an assembly with auto-injection macros. For example:

```
@protocol IFormatterProvider <NSObject>

- (id)statusTextFormatter;

@end

@interface MyAssembly : TyphoonAssembly <IFormatterProvider>
@end

@implementation MyAssembly

- (id <IFormatterProvider>)formatterProvider
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition with:self]; // First guess
}

- (id)statusTextFormatter
{
    // impl
}

@end
```

Then trying to use it in business logic file:

```
@interface MyStuff ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) InjectedProtocol(IFormatterProvider)formatterProvider;

@end
```

But getting the "No components defined which satisify type" error (btw there is a typo), because assembly got registered as `TyphoonInjectionDefinition` with class `NSObject`

Is it even possible to do what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the assembly itself, to act as a factory or provider, using [this approach](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself). This is an explicit wiring.

I don't believe that auto-wiring works for assembly protocols, however you may raise a feature request if that is of interest.

Comment: I see, wanted to make sure, that you can't avoid explicit injection. Added [issue](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/529)